# Spring Boot @RequestPart charset encoding

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have an endpoint which `consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` with `POST` method.

There are 2 arguments `@RequestPart(name = "model", required = true) String jsonPart, @RequestPart(name = "images", required = false) MultipartFile[] images`. The first argument is a `JSON` string which I'll use the `ObjectMapper` to parse into a `POJO` later which goes well and also the receive of the `Multipart[]`. Only problem is that the `name` value in the initial `JSON` string was not in the right encoding.

[image]

This is the `JSON` string from the `multipart-form/data request` which was properly parsed, here I'm giving it the value `White Lé FrÖÖnt`

[image]

This is the debugged `JSON` string in the `@RequestPart` giving `White LeÌ FrÃnt` which was not expected

Here are the suggestions that I've tried so far collected from browsing through the web

1. Adding `CharacterEncodingFilter` into Spring Security `FilterChain` as prioritized as possible
2. `server.servlet.encoding.enabled=true` and `server.servlet.encoding.force=true` or even `server.servlet.encoding.force=false` in application.properties

None of which work individually or collectively together. What I have in mind is that there's nothing wrong with the `request` but rather something that I need to add to the server in order for it to work. Thanks for your time, I appreciate any help.

Comment: 1. Is already there with Spring Boot so that won't change a bit and it should be part of the regular filter chain not the spring security filter chain. 2. is only for enforcing the embedded server (if you don't have an embedded server it doesn't do anything). That being said, do you actually send the encoding with the request? Else it will pick some default. Why don't you directly serialize into the object you need? Spring can perfectly handle that and saves you messing with an `ObjectMapper`. Also this is debugging, but is it really wrong or is it only wrong in your debugger?

Comment: Thanks for responding,
1. By "regular filter chain" did you mean the `HandlerInterceptor`?
2. Yes there is Tomcat embedded. I also looked up about "send the encoding with the request?", but what I found is that there's no allowance of the 'charset: utf-8' in the `Content-Type` and the header itself was automatically handled in the FormData, we don't explicitly do that

Comment: About serializing, if I was to do `@RequestPart(name = "model", required = true) Pojo model` Spring will response with the `405 Unsupported MediaType`. Only when I explicitly receive it as `JSON` string and parse it will Spring allow the request to hit into the process

Comment: For the debugger consideration, I can confirm it's showing the exact value since I have a method to validate the input values and check for `"^[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\s\\.\\,\\_\\-\\@\"'\\*{VIETNAMESE_CHARACTERS}]+$"` where the `{VIETNAMESE_CHARACTERS}` are typed out Vietnamese chacracters

Comment: How about `@RequestPart(name = "model", required = true) MultipartFile model` then get contents with `model.getBytes()` and pass that to ObjectMapper.

Comment: @LMC does that mean I have to parse the `JSON` into a file representation? And thus, the encoding will be preserved?

Comment: I believe so, getting plain bytes should preserve enconding.

Comment: It's late here, I'll try it out tomorrow and reply to you asap

Comment: @LMC I tried your approach and it worked, not only preserving the encoding but also solved the `405 Unsupported MediaType` when I'm trying to receive `@RequestPart` as POJO. Could be a misunderstanding of the framework from myself. If you could give your solution as an answer, I can mark it as correct. Thank you.

Comment: Using the POJO should work, if it doesn't and you get a 405, this means you aren't setting the explicit content type for that part of your multipart request and Spring doesn't know what to convert it into.

Comment: I didn't know that, I'll do that and let you know the result. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach to solve the issue could be to set the parameter type to `MultipartFile`

```
@RequestPart(name = "model", required = true) MultipartFile model
```

Then get contents with `model.getBytes()` and pass that to `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: To anyone who's implementing this solution, take notes that sending your `JSON` object as file takes up your upload threshold, which will be a consideration if you're working with a big object

Comment: ALthough it might work, using the POJO and let SPring do the marshalling should work as well.